# Using R Squared with Mean Very Close to 0

Tags: r-squared, model-evaluation

I am using $R^2$ to evaluate the quality of fitted model. The mean of the Y values in my model is very close to $0$, around $0.003$. This makes the denominator of the $R^2$ calculation very small, less than $1$, so I often get massively negative $R^2$ values, think $-2000$. Is there a way I can adjust $R^2$ so it is less biased by the very small denominator?

Comment: I think you’re calculating $R^2$ wrong. What equation are you using?

Comment: 1 - sum(model MSE)/sum(mean MSE)

Comment: Please write out the summations. What are you adding up? What are sum(model MSE) and sum(mean MSE)? I am not having issues with my simulation where the response variable has a mean that is even closer to zero than yours.

Comment: I sum the squared difference between my model prediction and actual observed for each observation as the numerator. I sum the squared difference between the sample mean and and actual observed for each observation as the numerator. Thanks!

Comment: Ala this: `https://miro.medium.com/max/1400/1*_HbrAW-tMRBli6ASD5Bttw.png`

Comment: Please type out the equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R^2 = 1 - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \hat{y_i})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - \bar{y})^2}$

$y_i$ is the $i^{th}$ observation of $y$.

$\hat{y_i}$ is predicted value of the the $i^{th}$ observation of $y$.

$\bar{y}$ is the mean value of all $y_i$.

$N$ is the number of observationf of $y$.

You're saying that $\bar{y}$ is tiny and that makes your denominator small. A small denominator could, conceivable, cause some issues when you divide on a computer, but short of that, a small denominator means an *even smaller* numerator, since the model will fit the data better than always guessing the average value of the response variable.$^{\dagger}$. Consequently, your fraction will still be in $(0,1)$, meaning that your $R^2$ is in $(0,1)$ like $R^2$ is supposed to be.

$^{\dagger}$I am assuming you're doing a linear regression, OLS-style model. If you're not, there might be bigger issues to discuss about using $R^2$. You also can wreck this idea if you do OLS without an intercept, but, almost always, that is a poor strategy.

**EDIT**

In `R`, $R^2$ can be calculated like this.

```
R2 <- 1 - (sum((y-predict(model))^2))/(sum((y-mean(y))^2))
```

Comment: Thanks. this helped me figure out the bug in my code

Comment: What was your mistake?

Comment: My denominator was just the sum of mean squared error over each observation, not the sum of observed-MSE.